# Print Qwebview as PDF through a loop

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to print multiple xml after transform it as html to pdf, below is my code when i try to run it only print the PDF files into output folder but only the last file get full content other files have only one page which is blank, I don't have an idea where it goes wrong.

```
 def process(self, MainWindow):
        inputpath = str(self.lineEdit.text())
        outputfile = str(self.lineEdit_2.text())

        tree = ET1.parse('config.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        xsltfile = root.findtext('xsltpath')
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith('.xml'):
                    inputfile = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    dom = ET.parse(inputfile)
                    xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
                    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
                    newdom = transform(dom)
                    infile = (ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
                    web = QWebView()
                    html = infile
                    web.setHtml( html )
                    filename2 = filename.rsplit(".", 1) [0]
                    outfil = outputfile + "\\" + filename2 + ".pdf"
                    printer = QPrinter()
                    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
                    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
                    printer.setOutputFileName(outfil)

                    def convertIt():
                        web.print_(printer)
                    QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
                    #web.show()
                    print outfil
                    time.sleep(20)                    
                    print ("processed")
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Completed', 'Process Completed')
```

**Edited**
When i put msg box "QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Completed', 'Process Completed')" inside the loop it gave me the correct output, the problem is because it print before fully load the file in webview, I have added "QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)" to check whether it has been fully load, it seems it's not working is there any better way to check it.

Comment: Why do you define `convertIt` inside `process`?

Comment: What do you mean by is not working? No output at all or just blank pages again?

Comment: Only one page which come as blank